# Classic ASP Hacks - Injection

Tags: security, asp-classic

In Classic ASP, I have used parameterized queries for all SQL queries in my application.

Do I need to protect a simple email form, which doesn't access a database?

Comment: Protect it from what?  If you don't use a database, you certainly don't need to be concerned with SQL injection, but you may need to worry about XSS and other common problems.

Comment: Where is the output of your form going?

Comment: It sends to the same page, where a Classic ASP script sends an email using the values entered in the form.

Comment: Protect it from anything Brad...

Comment: Yes, you should: you might want to post the data into some database at some point down the road. Best practices and all that.

Comment: You should always validate form entries.

Comment: @uotonyh — Best practise is to convert data to the target format immediately before using it. Making the data SQL safe in case you decide to insert it into a database later is pointless (which SQL dialect? What if you use a non-SQL based database?). Worse than pointless, in fact, because SQL safe means your escape characters will show up when used in a different context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Protecting from spam bots is a good idea. You wouldn't want other computers using your forms without your knowledge. Here are some suggestions:

1. Create an independent account that the page will send emails to. In case the address is overly spammed, you can switch to another one.
2. Use a CAPTCHA. I like [Mollom](http://mollom.com) because it only displays a CAPTCHA if an entry looks like spam, and this isn't intrusive to most real users.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested CAPTCHA is a good idea to avoid spam/food attacks, your mail server can queue up thousands of email which might cause serious problems and administrative overhead.

Another thing to be careful about is [Email Injection](http://www.securephpwiki.com/index.php/Email_Injection). This can allow an attacker to send spam emails via your server.